# Regex pattern to start with first digit and end at last hyphen (if it exists)

Tags: regex, vbscript

I have a regex pattern that almost works, but I can't quite get it totally correct.  My goal is that if a string starts with letters, to ignore them up to the first digit.  The second part of the pattern needs to make the match stop at the last hyphen in the string, if one exists.  Here are some examples of strings that I would be working on:

```
PCKG6JUB-0330M3-0-812   wanting returned 6JUB-0330M3-0
CCP352878               wanting returned 352878
0972543107              wanting returned 0972543107
```

This is the pattern that I have so far: `\d[\S]*-`  The problem is that on the top example, it includes the last hyphen in the match, so I get `6JUB-0330M3-0-`.  Also, if no hyphen exists, then nothing is returned.

I'm using the VBScript engine.

Comment: It is not clear what the requirements are. Are you collecting just first match from each input string? I have only come up with `\d\S*(?=-)|\d\S*`

Comment: I'm not sure how to answer that.  There should only be one match.  Sam's answer worked, so I'll go with that.  But thanks for trying to help, even if I wasn't clear enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
\d(?:\S*(?=-)|\S*)
```

First, I used a positive lookahead, `(?=...)`, so we don't actually match the last hyphen. Then, I used alternation, `|`, to check for a match with a hyphen or without a hyphen. So that we don't need to match the digit on both sides of the alternation, I put this part in a non-capturing group, `(?:...)`. Finally, `\S` is shorthand for a character class and doesn't need to be in brackets.

---

One would think we'd just be able to make the hyphen optional (i.e. `\d\S*(?=-?)`), but that doesn't work. This is because our `\S*` match is greedy   (and it needs to be, since you want to match up until the *last* hyphen) and will just blow right past the hyphen.

Comment: Doesnt quite work becuase you are still matching the 812 because of the \S* https://regex101.com/r/uT7jR2/1

Comment: @Nefariis I was working under the assumption that the OP was matching these strings one at a time, not all at once globally. If this is the case, OP can always anchor the match to the beginning of the string: [`/^.*?(\d(?:\S*(?=-)|\S*))/gm`](https://regex101.com/r/fZ8dN7/1)

Comment: @Sam  You are correct that each string will be processed one at a time.  So far, it works perfectly.  Thanks!

Comment: @Sam  I just discovered that this doesn't seem to work with spaces.  The case that I found has the text `83 web bv9774` and because it starts with a number and has no hyphen, I want it to return the whole string untouched.  However, I'm just getting **83**.  I tried replacing the capital **S** with a small case **s**, but that didn't work

Comment: @kb9zzo it's because I was using your `\S` character class (which means non-whitespace characters) from your example. Just replace the `\S` with `.` to match any characters.